# Different functions of QA Retrieval in Langchain

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I am confused between these functions in Langchain. what are the similarities and differences between these functions in Langchain:

- RetrievalQA,
- RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
- Load_qa_chain
- ConversationalRetrievalChain

and which one is better for implementing a retrieval chatbot with Memory and PromptTemplate? is there a better way for implementing the retrieval chatbot?

(please don't use chatGPT or other chatbots to answer because they are not accurate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms,

RetrievalQA is a method for question-answering tasks, utilizing an index to retrieve relevant documents or text chunks, it suits for straightforward Q&A applications.

RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain is an extension of RetrievalQA that chained together multiple sources of information, providing context and transparency in constructing comprehensive answers.

Load_qa_chain loads a pre-trained question-answering chain, specifying language model and chain type, suitable for applications using or reusing saved QA chains across sessions.

ConversationalRetrievalChain is a mehtod used for building a chatbot with memory and prompt template support. It combines chat history and current question into a current question, retrieves relevant documents, and generates a response. When context play important role for your applications ConversationalRetrievalChain would have upper edge